# An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreateRole operation: This policy contains invalid Json

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Trying to set up a trust policy so Log groups in other accounts can send to a separate account.  I'm following this article to the letter, with only changing the region and account IDs.

When running the command:

```
aws iam create-role \
    --role-name CWLtoKinesisRole \
    --assume-role-policy-document file://TrustPolicyForCWL.json
```

I get this error:

> An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreateRole operation: This policy contains invalid Json

Considering I'm copying the exact syntax they are providing, not sure what to do.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Here's the exact policy json I'm sending (only substituted out my account IDs for generic ones):

```json
{
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:SourceArn": [
                    "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:111111111111:*",
                    "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:999999999999:*"
                ]
            }
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the version definition, try this:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:SourceArn": [
                    "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:111111111111:",
                    "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:999999999999:"
                ]
            }
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
}
```